# Python + MongoDB - Cursor iteration too slow - Unresolved?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a database find query which returns 150k documents where each document contains three integer fields and one datetime field. The following code attempts to create a list from the cursor object. Iterating the cursor is incredibly slow - about 80 seconds! The same operation via the C++ drivers is orders of magnitude faster - it must be an issue with PyMongo?

```
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.taq
collection_str = "mycollection"
db_collection = db[collection_str]

mylist = list(db_collection.find())
```

This issue has been discussed before and I tried the suggestions. One is to change the default batch size. So I tried the following:

```
cursor = db_collection.find()
cursor.bath_size(10000)
mylist = list(cursor)
```

However, this had no impact. A second suggestion was to check that the C extensions are installed - I have them installed so this is not the issue. The Mongo database is installed on the same machine so it is not a network issue - it works fine from C++ ... querying from Pymongo is the issue.

Since MongoDB is marketed as being able to handle Big Data, surely there is a way to retrieve data quickly via Python? This issue has been raised before but I am yet to find a solution.... has anyone got a suggestion that works? It this case I am retrieving 150k documents, but normally the query would be retrieving 1million so this is going to be a real issue for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a sample document?  How much data is the 150k documents? 1 MB or 2.4GB?  How complex are the documents? Can you try to connect to the socket and not via tcp - does that improve the performance? Also why convert to a list?  You need to wait until all the data is across the wire before using it.  Aside from python how much RAM do you have?  Does running [touch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/touch/) on the collection to warm the cache improve performance?  Probably best to add a ticket to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON but a demo usecase would help debug

Comment: Each document is very simple containing a datetime field and three integer valued fields. I'm converting to a list so I can pass the list to the constructor of a Pandas DataFrame. Ignoring the list conversion, if I remove this line and just iterate the cursor it is still very slow. RAM is not an issue, there is 30GB of RAM on this server. The code I posted is enough to to recreate the problem. Attempt to iterate a cursor of 150k simple documents and see how long it takes.

Comment: how long does it take to iterate thru the cursor's results, but not put the items in a list? Nearly the same?

Comment: @Rob, In your code there is no iteration over cursor. In fact if you are creating DataFrame from list, you don't need iterations as well.. So, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Any update to this Rob?

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate - I'm loading 150k documents and converting to a list in ~0.5 > ~0.8 seconds.  Here are the results of the timeit test script - in seconds for converting 150,000 documents from the database into a list.

```
--------------------------------------------------
Default batch size
0.530369997025
--------------------------------------------------
Batch Size 1000
0.570069074631
--------------------------------------------------
Batch Size 10000
0.686305046082
```

Heres my test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import timeit

def main():
    """
    Testing loading 150k documents in pymongo
    """

    setup = """
import datetime
from random import randint
from pymongo import MongoClient
connection = MongoClient()
db = connection.test_load
sample = db.sample
if db.sample.count() < 150000:
    connection.drop_database('test_load')

    # Insert 150k sample data
    for i in xrange(15000):
        sample.insert([{"date": datetime.datetime.now(),
                        "int1": randint(0, 1000000),
                        "int2": randint(0, 1000000),
                        "int4": randint(0, 1000000)} for i in xrange(10)])

"""

    stmt = """
from pymongo import MongoClient
connection = MongoClient()

db = connection.test_load
sample = db.sample

cursor = sample.find()
test = list(cursor)
assert len(test) == 150000
"""

    print "-" * 100
    print """Default batch size"""
    t = timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt, setup=setup)
    print t.timeit(1)

    stmt = """
from pymongo import MongoClient
connection = MongoClient()

db = connection.test_load
sample = db.sample

cursor = sample.find()
cursor.batch_size(1000)
test = list(cursor)
assert len(test) == 150000
"""

    print "-" * 100
    print """Batch Size 1000"""
    t = timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt, setup=setup)
    print t.timeit(1)

    stmt = """
from pymongo import MongoClient
connection = MongoClient()

db = connection.test_load
sample = db.sample

cursor = sample.find()
cursor.batch_size(10000)
test = list(cursor)
assert len(test) == 150000
"""

    print "-" * 100
    print """Batch Size 10000"""
    t = timeit.Timer(stmt=stmt, setup=setup)
    print t.timeit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm confused as to how you are getting 80 seconds rather than 0.8!  I created my sample data based on your definition - how different is that to yours?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help if you're returning every item in your collection (vs. querying by certain fields), but have you tried creating indexes for your fields?

```
db_collection.create_index([("field_name", pymongo.ASCENDING)])
db_collection.reindex()
```

Docs: https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html